# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an integral operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, integral-equations

I need to find the eigenvalues e eigenvectors of this integral.

$$\int_{0}^{1} K(x,y)\phi (y)dy,$$

where

$K(x,y)=x(1-y),\; 0 \le x\le y \le 1$

and

$K(x,y)=y(1-x),$ $0\le y\le x \le 1$

I really need an explanation here so I can solve the rest of the exercises that I have here.

Comment: Please can You help me out???

Comment: I really need help on this, I'm tying to solve this for about a week and I can't... Can you please help? This is for an assignment!

Comment: I'm pretty sure shouting won't get you any more help. On the contrary, even. What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know where to begin because I don't understand what to do mainly...

Comment: I know how to solve second kind Fredholm integral equations but this one I don't get the meaning and what to do with it

Comment: Can you explain me please

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: Can you please explain me what this is about??? I really don't understand the concept and can't solve it

Answer (score 15):

Eigenvalues of this integral operator are those values of $\lambda$ for which the equation
$$(1-x) \int_0^x y\phi(y)dy + x \int_x^1 (1-y)\phi(y)dy = \lambda \phi(x)$$
has non-trivial solutions. Putting $x=0$, $x=1$ in this equation and differentiating this equation twice it follows that
$$-\phi(x)=\lambda \phi''(x), \quad \phi(0)=\phi(1)=0.$$
It is obvious that $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue. The general solution is $$\phi(x)=A \cos \frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}} + B \sin \frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$
and $\phi(0)=0$ implies $A=0$. So eigenvalues are exactly the roots of the equation
$$\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\lambda_n=\frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2}, \quad n=1,2,3,\ldots$$
Corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$\sin n \pi x, \quad n=1,2,3,\ldots$$

Comment: The OP hasn't specified the domain of definition, but for integral operators this is usually some $L^2$ spaces, so why do you assume that $\phi$ is differentiable, given that it may not be? In other words, you should prove that there are no other eigenfunctions (and eigenvalues) besides the ones that you have found.

Comment: Interestingly (and orthogonally to the OP's question), due to regularity properties of $K$,  it's is possible to get that $\lambda_n = \mathcal O(n^{-2})$ without actually computing it

Comment: @AlexM.: if $\lambda\ne0$, then $\phi$ is differentiable.